# Why is creating a ring buffer shared by different processes so hard (in C++), what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c++, shared-memory, circular-buffer, boost-interprocess

I am being especially dense about this but it seems I'm missing an important, basic point or something, since what I want to do should be common:

I need to create a fixed-size ring buffer object from a manager process (`Process M`). This object has `write()` and `read()` methods to write/read from the buffer. The read/write methods will be called by independent processes (`Process R` and `W`)

I have implemented the buffer, `SharedBuffer<T&>`, it allocates buffer slots in SHM using boost::interprocess and works perfectly *within a single process*. I have read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953381/instantiating-objects-in-shared-memory-c) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131397/how-to-get-shared-object-in-shared-memory) on SO, as well as asked [my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423270/adding-an-allocator-to-a-c-class-template-for-shared-memory-object-creation), but I'm still in the dark about how to have different processes access methods from a common object. The Boost doc has an example of [creating a vector in SHM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container), which is very similar to what I want, but I want to instantiate my own class.

My current options are:

1. Use placement `new`, as suggested by Charles B. to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423270/adding-an-allocator-to-a-c-class-template-for-shared-memory-object-creation); however, he cautions that it's not a good idea to put non-POD objects in SHM. But my class needs the read/write methods, how can I handle those?
2. Add an allocator to my class definition, e.g. have `SharedBuffer<T&, Alloc>` and proceed similarly to the [vector example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) given in boost. This sounds really complicated.
3. Change `SharedBuffer` to a POD class, i.e. get rid of all the methods. But then how to synchronize reading and writing between processes?

What am I missing? Fixed-length ring buffers are very common, so either this problem has a solution or else I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'll add #4 - write  a server process to manage the data. The basic rule about multi-process software is that something (i.e. one process) has to be in charge of a shared resource.

Comment: Exactly. That was what I was aiming with the management process that will create the buffer, check how full it is, etc.

Comment: But if you have such a process, all issues of placement new, use of shared memory etc. go away. You of course have new interesting issues like how to talk to the server, but those are well understood in the biz.

Comment: Agree with @Neil, additionally you can pick up unexpected side-benefits too, like being able to spread your clients around to multiple machines.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you considered using a pipe and letting the OS take care of the synchronization for you?

Comment: The ring buffer is where a video decoder (writer) will place decoded video frames for processors (readers) to read, so speed is important. I didn't go the pipes way since I though SHM would buy me much more speed.

Answer (score 1):

The ring buffer is not a problem here, using shared memory is. The solution to that is using placement new for allocating your object, or at least for allocation of an internal buffer of it. Simply having member functions, constructors and destructors shouldn't cause trouble, but make sure that you do not use virtual functions or contain non-POD objects, as that may get tricky.

Comment: Virtual functions won't work at all, and there is no way to make them work.